# Certificate Authentication against LDAP with Spring Boot/ Spring Secruity

Tags: authentication, spring-security, ldap, certificate, spring-boot

i'm currently trying to implement a Spring Boot webservice with mutual authentication that expects a user certifiace and authenticates and authorizes a user with the details it contains against a ldap server.

The mutual authentication works so far, that the server identifies himself to the user and asks for an user certificate. With an example in-memory user the whole authentication and authorization process works fine. However as soon as I implement the LDAP connection I get an "java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required." exception. Interesting though is that the LDAP configuration itself is working fine when I use an login page where a user is has to prompt his credetnials manualy. So in Short:

Login Page + LDAP works,

CERT + in-memory User works,

CERT + LDAP does not work.

here is my Code so far:

web/config/Application.java

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan({ "web.*" })
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return viewResolver;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

        @Bean
        public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
            tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
            return tomcat;
        }

        // *************************************************************************************************
        // Mutual Cert Authentication
        // *************************************************************************************************
        private Connector createSslConnector() {
            Connector connector = new Connector(
                    "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
            Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector
                    .getProtocolHandler();
            try {
                File keystore = new ClassPathResource("server.jks").getFile();
                File truststore = new ClassPathResource("cacerts.jks").getFile();
                connector.setScheme("https");
                connector.setSecure(true);
                connector.setPort(8443);
                protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
                protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystore.getAbsolutePath());
                protocol.setKeystorePass("toor");   //example password
                protocol.setTruststoreFile(truststore.getAbsolutePath());
                protocol.setTruststorePass("toor"); //example passsword
                protocol.setKeyAlias("server");
                protocol.setClientAuth("want");
                protocol.setSslProtocol("TLS");

                return connector;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                 throw new IllegalStateException("can't access keystore: ["
                + "keystore" + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
            }
        }

        // *************************************************************************************************
        // The Authentication Manager Bean provides the source that userdata gets
        // authenticated against. In this Scenario a ldap server is used.
        // *************************************************************************************************
        @Bean
        public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource getSource() throws Exception {

            String address = "ldap://lokalhost:389/dc=ldap";  //example url
            String ldapUser = "cn=admin,dc=ldap";             //example login
            String ldapPassword = "toor";                     //example password

            DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource source = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
                address);
            source.setUserDn(ldapUser);
            source.setPassword(ldapPassword);
            source.afterPropertiesSet();
            return source;
         }
     }
```

web/config/WebSecurity.java

```
     @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


                @Autowired
                private DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource source;

                 @Autowired
                public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

                    auth.ldapAuthentication().contextSource(source)
                            .userSearchBase("dc=users,dc=ldap")
                            .userDnPatterns("cn={0},dc=users")
                            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                            ;   
                }


            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                 // *************************************************************************************************
                // Insert pages that need propper authentication/authorization here
                // *************************************************************************************************
                http
                .x509().subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?),").and()    
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

            }
         }
```

The pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>SpringCertAuth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cert-authentication</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- ldap -->
       <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end ldap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

        <properties>
            <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>    
    </project>
```

The web/controller/HomeController.java

```
     @Controller
         public class HomeController {

            @RequestMapping("/welcome")
            public ModelAndView index() {
                ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
                model.addObject("title","Secure Web Application");
                model.addObject("message", "this is the welcome page");
                model.setViewName("welcome");       
                return model;       
        }
    }
```

And the webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp

```
    <%@page session="false"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <html>
    <body>
        <h1>Title : ${title}</h1>   
        <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PS: The certificates I am using are self signed and lie in the src/main/resources folder.

I hope someone can help me.

Best regards
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution. I rewrote the Application class to:

```
.
.
.
    public static DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource getSource() throws Exception {

        String address = "ldap://lokalhost:389/dc=ldap";  //example url
        String ldapUser = "cn=admin,dc=ldap";             //example login
        String ldapPassword = "toor";                     //example password

        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource source = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
                address);
        source.setUserDn(ldapUser);
        source.setPassword(ldapPassword);
        source.afterPropertiesSet();
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public static LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthProvider() throws Exception{

        LdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator(),authPopulator()); 

        return provider;
    }


    @Bean
    public static BindAuthenticator authenticator() throws Exception{
        String[] userDn = {"cn={0},dc=users"}; 

        BindAuthenticator auth = new BindAuthenticator(getSource());
        auth.setUserDnPatterns(userDn);
        return auth;

    }
    //authenticator2 only neccessary if authentiction with passwordcompare instead of binduser is wanted.
    @Bean
    public static PasswordComparisonAuthenticator authenticator2() throws Exception{
        String[] userDn = {"cn={0},dc=users"}; 
        PasswordComparisonAuthenticator auth = new  PasswordComparisonAuthenticator(getSource());
         auth.setUserDnPatterns(userDn);
         auth.setPasswordAttributeName("userPassword");
         auth.setPasswordEncoder(Md5Encoder());

         return auth;

    }

    @Bean
    public static DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator authPopulator() throws Exception{

        DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator authPop = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(getSource(),"dc=groups"); 
        authPop.setGroupRoleAttribute("cn");
        authPop.setGroupSearchFilter("(member={0})");
        return authPop;
    }

    //Certificate Authentication
    @Bean
    public static LdapUserDetailsService CustomLdapUserDetailsService() throws Exception{
        LdapUserDetailsService userDetails = new LdapUserDetailsService(userSearch(),authPopulator());
        return userDetails;

    } 
    @Bean
    public static FilterBasedLdapUserSearch userSearch() throws Exception{
        FilterBasedLdapUserSearch search = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch("","cn={0}",getSource());
        return search;      
    }
}
```

Also I changed the WebSecurityConfig class a little. Now it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {


    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

        auth.authenticationProvider(Application.ldapAuthProvider());

    }


     @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // *************************************************************************************************
        // Insert pages that need proper authentication/authorization here
        // *************************************************************************************************
        http
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
        .x509().subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?),").userDetailsService(Application.CustomLdapUserDetailsService())
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/profile/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_VIEW') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')")
        .antMatchers("/welcome**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/authenticate").access("hasRole('ROLE_VIEW') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("/admin").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')")
        .and()
        .formLogin()        
        .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/welcome?logout").logoutUrl("/logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")        
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()

        ;           
    }
}
```

The last clue gave me this post here:
[spring-security : Using user's certificate to authenticate against LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936371/spring-security-using-users-certificate-to-authenticate-against-ldap)

I hope I can help someone with that.

Regards
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

You have to add UserDetailService on your web/config/WebSecurity.java file.

As an example

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .x509()
        .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
            if (username.equals("Bob")) {
                return new User(username, "", 
                  AuthorityUtils
                    .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
            }
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
        }
    };
}
```

Hope, this works.